# Is there any good way to know if a water-mass is safe to bathe in?

Tags: hot-springs, lakes, salt-lakes

There is a lot of pollution around, and a lot of abuses of the natural resources.  For example, on I-80 in Nevada, it is not uncommon to see some sort of man-made factories around what appears to be natural hot-springs (what do they usually do?), plus there's also always a danger of natural pathogens like E. coli.

Is there any good way to determine if a given body of water (lake, salt lake, hot spring) is safe to submerge oneself into?

Comment: Even a beach with many people already bathing is not a reliable indicator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to bathe off of I-80 in Utah if there is a watermass?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18516/is-it-safe-to-bathe-off-of-i-80-in-utah-if-there-is-a-watermass)

Comment: @MarcelC. - Not exactly: this one asks for all waters in the world.

Comment: Then the other one is a duplicate. If not, I think that some people might even argue that this question is too broad etc.

Comment: @MarcelC. - I agree with you. Moreover, I think that this is more suited to [outdoors SE](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4):

In France, there is the "Pavillon Bleu" label which marks beaches where water quality is such that you can bathe safely.

This has spread internationally, as the [Blue Flag](http://www.blueflag.org) programme.

From the site:

> The Blue Flag is a voluntary eco-label awarded to more than 3850
>   beaches and marinas in 48 countries across Europe, South Africa,
>   Morocco, Tunisia, New Zealand, Brazil, Canada and the Caribbean.
>
> The Blue Flag works towards sustainable development of beaches and
>   marinas through strict criteria dealing with Water Quality,
>   Environmental Education and Information, Environmental Management, and
>   Safety and Other Services.
>
> The Blue Flag Programme is owned and run by the non-government,
>   non-profit organisation the Foundation for Environmental Education
>   (FEE).

Unfortunately, Nevada (and USA) is not part of that programme.

Comment: Nevada doesn't have any beaches anyway :)